# How would I reduce nesting for form validation in PHP?

Tags: php

This is function is taking up a lot of lines on my Functions page.

I can't figure out on how to take it down unless putting them into an array, then using a `foreach` loop. But I want it to be specific on what is not allowed to be blank.

```
if ($EmployeeID === "")
{
  echo "EmployeeID Is Blank.";

}
else
{
  if ($Firstname === "")
  {
    echo "Firstname Is Blank.";
  }
  else
  {
    if ($Lastname === "")
    {
      echo "Last Name Is Blank";

    }
    else
    {
      if ($PhoneNumber === "")
      {
        echo "Phone Number Is Blank";

      }
      else
      {
        if ($Address === "")
        {
          echo "Address Is Blank";

        }
        else
        {
          if ($City === "")
          {
            echo "City Is Blank";

          }
          else
          {
            if ($State === "")
            {
              echo "Sate Is Blank";

            }
            else
            {
              if ($Zip === "")
              {
                echo "Zip Is Blank";

              }
              else
              {
                if ($Email === "")
                {
                  echo "Email Is Blank";

                }
                else
                {
                  if ($Password === "")
                  {
                    echo "Password Is Blank";

                  }
                  else
                  {
                    echo "All Success";
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Solution I have Found which takes the lines down, but doesn't give me the exact on what field is left empty is:

```
$Array = array();
$Array[] = $EmpID;
$Array[] = $FirstName;
$Array[] = $Lastname;
$Array[] = $PhoneNumber;
$Array[] = $Address;
$Array[] = $City;
$Array[] = $State;
$Array[] = $Zip;
$Array[] = $Email;
$Array[] = $Password;   
foreach ($Array AS $Checking) 
{
  if (empty($Checking))
  {
    echo "One Or More Is Left Blank"; 
    exit;
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all use the `empty()` function

Comment: make 1 string from all of it =)

Comment: If I make it into 1 string, then I will have trouble looking for the exact input field is left blank

Comment: @EL2002 That's a terrible suggestion and it can't help.

Comment: another option: use form data as associative array. <input type="hidden" name="Option[EmployeeID][CastError]" value="EmployeeID is blank"><input type="text" name="Option[EmployeeID][value]" value="">etc... and then walk it with foreach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
try{
    if(empty($EmployeeID)){
        throw new Exception('EmployeeID Is Blank.');
    }elseif(empty($Firstname)){
        throw new Exception('Firstname Is Blank.');
    }elseif(empty($Lastname)){
        throw new Exception('Lastname Is Blank.');
    }elseif(empty($PhoneNumber)){
        throw new Exception('PhoneNumber Is Blank.');
    }elseif(empty($Address)){
        throw new Exception('Address Is Blank.');
    }elseif(empty($City)){
        throw new Exception('City Is Blank.');
    }elseif(empty($State)){
        throw new Exception('State Is Blank.');
    }elseif(empty($Zip)){
        throw new Exception('Zip Is Blank.');
    }elseif(empty($Email)){
        throw new Exception('Email Is Blank.');
    }elseif(empty($Password)){
        throw new Exception('Password Is Blank.');
    }
    echo 'All Success';
}catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: +1 Good answer, but probably a bit too advanced for this guy :-)

Comment: As The Above Said, a little bit too advanced for this little  code newb, over to PHP.net to look at the functions used :)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can reorganize it like this:

```
$messages = array();

if (empty($EmployeeID)){
    $messages[] = "EmployeeID Is Blank."; 
}
if (empty($Firstname)){
    $messages[] = "Firstname Is Blank."; 
}

// and so on for the rest.
```

At the end you can check if `$messages` is empty to validate:

```
if (empty($messages)){
    echo "All Success";
}else {
   echo "Errors:";
   foreach($messages as $message){
       echo "$message <br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, Checking that each of the variables are left blank, adding them into an array the the end result is printing out all the messages in 1 easy chunk

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using al these `else` statements? I would present all errors all at once to avoid messing with the user (the user fixes the error and then all of a sudden another pops up...).

An easy example:

```
echo empty($EmployeeID) ? 'EmployeeID Is Blank.' : '';
echo empty($Firstname) ? 'Firstname Is Blank.' : '';
//etc.
```

I would probably add all error messages to an array and loop through that / check if it is empty:

```
$errors = array();

if (empty($EmployeeID))
{
  $errors['employeeid'] = 'EmployeeID Is Blank.';
}
if (empty($Firstname))
{
  $errors['firstname'] = 'Firstname Is Blank.';
}
// etc.

if (count($errors) > 0)
{
  // error handling
}

// and you can use the array keys to display the appropriate messages at the appropriate place if it is set:
if (isset($errors['employeeid']))
{
  // display the EmployeeID error message where the field should be filled in
}
```

Comment: I'm not with the usage of the ? and : operators :/

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) like this:

```
$formValues = array(
  'Employee ID' => $EmployeeID,
  'First Name' => $Firstname,
  'Last Name'=> $Lastname,
  'Phone Number'=> $PhoneNumber,
  'Address'=> $Address,
  'City'=> $City,
  'State'=> $State,
  'Zip'=> $Zip,
  'Email'=> $Email,
  'Password'=> $Password,
);
$error=false;

foreach ($formValues as $key => $value) {
  if(empty($value)) {
    echo($key.' is blank');
    $error=true;
  }
}
if(!$error) {
  echo("All Success");
}
```

Comment: i think you mixed javascript and php, declaring an array in php is done like so: `$formValues = array('Employee ID' => $EmployeeID,...)`

Comment: In PHP 5.4+ you can use the JavaScript style :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it all up in a form validator:

```
<?php
  function is_form_valid() {
    if ($Firstname === "") { return false; }
    if ($Lastname === "") { return false; }
    // ...

    return true;
  }
?>
```

Of course, this only highlights the idea and you will need to determine the best method for passing in your form fields.  Then use that as a single call in your main processing routine:

```
<?php

  if (is_form_valid()) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    // report error
  }
?>
```

To make it more useful, you can create a shared class for valid input in name fields, emails, etc and call that from your form validation.  Imagining such a class exists, your method would look like:

```
<?php
  function is_form_valid() {
    if (! $validator->is_valid_name($Firstname)) { return false; }
    if (! $validator->is_valid_name($Lastname)) { return false; }
    if (! $validator->is_valid_email($Email)) { return false; }
    if (! $validator->is_valid_phone($Phone)) { return false; }
    // ...

    return true;
  }
?>
```

Just be aware of the many regional differences regarding names, phone numbers, addresses, etc.  You can read about common pitfalls [here](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).  There are also several questions on this forum about the subject of data validation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$errors = "";

if($EmployeeID == "")
{
    $errors .= "Employee ID blank<br />";
}

if($Firstname == "")
{
    $errors .= "First Name blank<br />";
}

if($errors != "")
{
    echo $errors;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of the other answers are better, but you should also learn to use `elseif()`:

```
if ($EmployeeID === "") {
    echo "EmployeeID Is Blank.";
} elseif ($Firstname === "") {
    echo "Firstname Is Blank.";
} elseif ($Lastname === "") {
    echo "Last Name Is Blank";
} //etc
```